# How do you get LibreOffice Calc to make sorted tables?

Tags: 12.10, libreoffice

Now by sorted tables I should clarify. I'd like LibreOffice calc to create tables with the same functionalities as those formed in Microsoft Excel 2007/2010 when the table data is selected and `ctrl+T` is pressed. When I sort a column I want all the columns to change accordingly so that each row is lined up properly. I am running LibreOffice 3.6.4 on 12.10 if these details are necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm giving a small example here:

```
Ser. No.    Bank    Amount  Rate %  -Cum/Qtrly- Started on  Ending On
1   Syn 20,00,000.00    9.35    Q   8 Feb 2012  8 Jan 2015 
2   Syn 3,00,000.00     9.25    Cum 19 Apr 2012     19 Apr 2022 
3   Syn 2,00,000.00     9.25    Cum 19 Apr 2012     19 Apr 2022 
4   Syn 5,00,000.00     8.50    Cum 26 Apr 2012     26 Apr 2022 
5   Axis    4,00,000.00     9.25    Cum 8 Jun 2012  8 Jun 2013 
6   Axis    45,000.00   6.15    Cum 28 Jul 2003     28 Jul 2013 
7   Axis    40,000.00   6.15    Cum 28 Jul 2003     28 Jul 2013 
8   Axis    45,000.00   6.15    Cum 28 Jul 2003     28 Jul 2013 
9   Axis    49,000.00   8.50    Cum 18 Dec 2012     18 Jan 2014 
10  Axis    49,000.00   8.50    Cum 18 Dec 2012     18 Jan 2014 
11  SBI 10,00,000.00    9.25    Q   23 Feb 2012     23 Feb 2022 
12  SBI 4,52,115.00     9.00    Cum 24 Jul 2012     24 Jun 2017 
13  SBI 1,97,149.00     9.25    Cum 24 Dec 2011     24 Apr 2021 
14  SBI 29,585.00   9.25    Cum 5 Jul 2011  31 Mar 2014 
15  SBI 1,83,946.00     9.25    Cum 24 Dec 2011     24 Apr 2021 
16  HDFC    8,50,000.00     8.75    Cum 17 Sep 2012     3 Oct 2013 
17  HDFC    10,00,000.00    9.25    Q   5 Mar 2012  5 Mar 2017 
18  HDFC    10,00,000.00    9.25    Cum 5 Mar 2012  5 Mar 2017
```

I click anywhere in this table. Then, in the menu bar, I click on Data, Sort. At this point I can choose which column to sort by. The data in other columns get sorted as well.

You could be experiencing problems if there are blank rows or columns in your table or your table is otherwise malformed.

If you wish, please upload a small spreadsheet **in .ods format**.

Answer (score 13):

**AutoFilter** (does the same thing as Insert Table in Excel)

This feature is called **AutoFilter** in Calc

1. Select your data range
2. Click: Data → Filter → AutoFilter

To add a single-click button, just add the Tools Toolbar to your view:

1. Click: View → Toolbars → Tools

...You will now have an AutoFilter button on your toolbar.